# How to access file from aws s3 bucket?

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How to access file from aws s3 bucket after upload the image to s3 bucket. When i am getting the image it shown access denied error.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>xxxxx</RequestId>
<HostId>xxxxx</HostId>
</Error>

Controller Code is

$sharedConfig = [
                 'region' => Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.region'),
                 'version' => 'latest',
                 "Effect" => "Allow",
                 'credentials' => [
                   'key' => 'xxxx',
                   'secret' => 'xxxx'
                  ]
                ];
               $sdk = new \Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);
               $s3 = $sdk->createS3();
               $res = $s3->putObject([
               'Key' => $fileName, // This will overwrite any other files with same name
               'SourceFile' => $filePath,
               'Bucket' => 'bolttupload'
              ]);
              Storage::copy($res['ObjectURL'],$destinationPath.$fileName);
              echo $res['ObjectURL'];die;
```

Comment: There can be multiple reasons, but it seems like a permission issue. Can you check the bucket permission to the role which assumes to access the bucket?

Comment: How are you accessing the object -- in a web browser? What URL are you using? By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private unless you set permission on the object, bucket or user. What makes you think that the object should be accessible? Have you assigned a Bucket Policy? If so, please show us.

Comment: @Ashan, I had given full permission to bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I am accessing the object from web browser and i have use that url which is return by the aws s3 bucket, when i was upload the object. I did not assign any bucket policy to that bucket.

Comment: @RajeevVarshney did you find any solution for how to access any images or file from s3 bucket using php ?

Comment: @Camit1dk take reference from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html

Answer (score 3):

By default, object in Amazon S3 are private. You can grant access to an object in several ways:

- **Access Control List** on an individual object ("Make this object public")
- **Bucket Policy** on the bucket ("Make this bucket or directory public")
- Via **permissions granted to an IAM User** ("This user can access this bucket or directory)
- Via **pre-signed URLs** ("This link will work for the next 5 minutes")

The URL you are using to access your object does not identify you as an authorised user. You have no Bucket Policy. Your object is not public. Therefore, you are **correctly receiving an Access Denied message**.

To make it accessible, you have to decide the scope of access based on the above list. If you want the **object** to be fully public, set that option on the object when you upload it:

```
$result = $client->putObject([
    'ACL' => 'private|public-read|public-read-write|authenticated-read|aws-exec-read|bucket-owner-read|bucket-owner-full-control',
...
```

If you want the **whole bucket or a directory** public, use a [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

If you only want **certain users** to access it, add a policy against the IAM User or IAM Group and then access the object with credentials that identify the user.

If you want your application to **determine at run-time** who should access the object, use a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html).